# Updating Tables MySql/PHP - inserting variable name instead of values

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i've searched too much about it, but, i'm not even rookie in PHP scripting... so I need     help.

i'm developing a homemade system to home automation, based on PHP/MySql, and, i need a backend to update the database tables and make things really happen in live.

so, i found the code i need, and, after some adaptation, here it is.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "domonet";
$tabela = "AtuadorAnalogico";
$valor1 = "AA_id";
$valor2 = "AA_nome";
$valor3 = "AA_valor";

//connection to the database

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with

$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");
  echo "Connected ao banco<br>";

//get data from db

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabela");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

//start a table

echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="292" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">';

//start header of table

echo '<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>';

//loop through all results

while($r=mysql_fetch_object($sql)){

//print out table contents and add id into an array and email into an array

echo '<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value='.$r->$valor1.' readonly></td>
<td>'.$r->$valor2.'</td>
<td><input name="email[]" type="text" id="price" value="'.$r->$valor3.'"></td>
</tr>';
}

//submit button


echo' <tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';


// if form has been submitted, process it


if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
   // get data from form
   
 $name = $_POST['name'];
   
   // loop through all array items
   
   foreach($_POST['id'] as $value)
   {
    
   // minus value by 1 since arrays start at 0      
   
           $item = $value-1;
           
                //update table
              
    //appending suggested changes  
    //place of var_dumps
   //$sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tabela SET $valor3='$valor3[$item]' WHERE     $valor1='$value'") or die(mysql_error());
   $sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tabela SET $valor3='$email[$item]' WHERE $valor1='$value'") or die(mysql_error());


                                
   }

// redirect user

$_SESSION['success'] = 'Updated';
header("location:index.php");
}
```

The problem is, after clicking at the 'submit' button, the database table just get weird.

```
From This:
mysql> select * from AtuadorAnalogico;
+-------+---------+----------+
| AA_id | AA_nome | AA_valor |
+-------+---------+----------+
|     0 | nome1   | d        |
|     1 | nome2   | Agfd     |
|     2 | nome3   | Aasd     |
|     3 | nome4   | _asda    |
|     5 | teste5  | a        |
|     6 | teste6  | asda     |
|     7 | testte1 | o        |
|     8 | testte2 | rwqdq    |
|     9 | asdadsd | gwrg     |
|    10 | asdadsd | qdw      |
|    11 | adasd   | 234      |
|    12 | adasd   | g42      |
+-------+---------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
To This:
mysql> select * from AtuadorAnalogico
+-------+---------+----------+
| AA_id | AA_nome | AA_valor |
+-------+---------+----------+
|     0 | nome1   |          |
|     1 | nome2   |          |
|     2 | nome3   |          |
|     3 | nome4   |          |
|     5 | teste5  |          |
|     6 | teste6  |          |
|     7 | testte1 |          |
|     8 | testte2 |          |
|     9 | asdadsd |          |
|    10 | asdadsd |          |
|    11 | adasd   |          |
|    12 | adasd   |          |
+-------+---------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please, I really can't see my mistake.

Thanks a lot for the code revision.

PS.: just to remember. When i run the php in browser, it DOES show the contents of the database table just as it is. after clicking the submit, the thing goes crazy.

## EDIT1

after renaming 'valor3' to 'email', it is not writing the string to the table anymore.
but, leaving the whole column blank (writing blank in all column cells as shown above) .

## EDIT2

in comments, we just figured that is a logical problem with the code.
just can't figure out what to do.

## Update

```
the output from just before the sql1 query:
var_dump($email);
var_dump($tabela);
var_dump($item);
var_dump($valor3);
var_dump($valor1);
var_dump($value);

vardump $email: NULL
vardump $tabela: string(16) "AtuadorAnalogico"
vardump $item: int(-1)
vardump $valor3: string(8) "AA_valor"
vardump $valor1: string(5) "AA_id"
vardump $value: string(1) "0"

vardump $email: NULL
vardump $tabela: string(16) "AtuadorAnalogico"
vardump $item: int(0)
vardump $valor3: string(8) "AA_valor"
vardump $valor1: string(5) "AA_id"
vardump $value: string(1) "1"
vardump $email: NULL

vardump $tabela: string(16) "AtuadorAnalogico"
vardump $item: int(1)
vardump $valor3: string(8) "AA_valor"
vardump $valor1: string(5) "AA_id"
vardump $value: string(1) "2"
```

ps.: i reduced the number of rows, so makes easyer to see and think.

## I FOUND IT!

stack didn't allowed me to answer my own question, so, i'm editing as they wish.

renaming this line fields 'name' and 'id' to ""anything"":

```
<td><input name="valores[]" type="text" id="valores" value="'.$r->$valor3.'"></td>
```

renaming this to the same as before:

```
     $valores = $_POST['valores'];
```

changing this to EQUAL (as stated by @JA):

```
  $item = $value;
```

and adapting the query like this:

```
    $sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tabela SET $valor3='$valores[$item]' WHERE $valor1='$value'") or die(mysql_error());
```

and IT's DONE!

## Thanks so much for your brainstorming.

and special thanks for @arielnmz who gave me the idea of dumping the vars so i can find the logic error.

by the way, the code finished.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "domonet";
$tabela = "AtuadorAnalogico";
$valor1 = "AA_id";
$valor2 = "AA_nome";
$valor3 = "AA_valor";

//connection to the database

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with

$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");
  echo "Connected ao banco<br>";

//get data from db

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabela");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

//start a table

echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="292" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">';

//start header of table

echo '<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>';

//loop through all results

while($r=mysql_fetch_object($sql)){

//print out table contents and add id into an array and email into an array
    
echo '<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value='.$r->$valor1.' readonly></td>
<td>'.$r->$valor2.'</td>
<td><input name="valores[]" type="text" id="valores" value="'.$r->$valor3.'"></td>
</tr>';
}

//submit button
    

echo' <tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';

// if form has been submitted, process it

if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
       // get data from form
       
     $valores = $_POST['valores'];
     
       // loop through all array items
       
   foreach($_POST['id'] as $value)
       {
       // minus value by 1 since arrays start at 0 (not anymore)
        
               $item = $value;
                //update table

       $sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tabela SET $valor3='$valores[$item]' WHERE     $valor1='$value'") or die(mysql_error());

   }

// redirect user

$_SESSION['success'] = 'Updated';
header("location:index.php");
};
```

Everybody have a great night!

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `SET $valor3 = '$valor3[$item]'`. `$valor3` is a string, not an array, why are you indexing it?

Comment: Make sense. But, when i change it for the array created in the form, just nothing happens. All blank

Comment: Then you're doing that wrong. Please append the updated code to the question. Also show the HTML of the form so we can tell if you're accessing the right `$_POST` variables.

Comment: $item = $value-1 What you mean by that? And there's no user posted value for $valor3.

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be something like `SET $valor3 = '{$_POST[$valor3][$item]}'`?

Comment: @Barmar Think you are right. Just found out the op was setting email field values with "valor3". So, to summarise, SET $valor3 = '{$_POST['email'][$item]}

Comment: It is quite brain storming when form elements are named like this.. name="email[]" type="text" id="price" value="..."> and contain values like "A", "788", "_" !!

Comment: Are you sure `$email` is a vector? What does `var_dump` say about it?

Comment: i am not sure. but, in this '<td><input name="email[]" type="text" id="price" value="'.$r->$valor3.'"></td>' I'm filling an array with this values, aren't I?

Comment: outputs this no /apache/log PHP Notice:  Undefined index: AA_valor

Comment: Sorry, I was just being sarcastic about the naming conventions where you name your element as email, style as price and have no relevance to the values you are storing. Would invite some headache when reviewing ;)

Comment: @Barmar The code you suggested just got all blank.

Comment: Then $email isn't a vector, and you're still trying to use it as vector, check that it's not being redefined later on the code. Just for the record: a numeric index (which you must use with $email) is different to an associative key. You should define the name like this: $email[$value3] if you want it to be associative, look out to not overwrite on that key.

Comment: @JA Actually, this code was got around the web, and i adapted as i needed. but, changing names is corrupting him. so i tried to leave as original as possible as long as it works, so after i can rename safely. but is not even working.

Comment: @arielnmz why id[] is a vector and email[] isn't ?!

Comment: @user3808783: Have you tried SET $valor3 = '{$_POST['email'][$value]}' ?

Comment: @JA yes. it just acts the same. all blank.

Comment: @user3808783 you just said that according to `var_dump` it isn't.

Comment: @arielnmz sorry for dumbness. probably i didn't got the concept of vectors in php well. i'm gonna study more about it.

Comment: @rt3norio You still haven't figured out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form element for email as following..

```
<input name="email['.$r->$valor1.']" type="text" id="price" value="'.$r->$valor3.'">
```

You can get rid of "id[]" element

Then the loop,

```
foreach($_POST['email'] as $id=>$value)

$sql1 = mysql_query('UPDATE '.$tabela.' SET '.$valor3.'="'.$value.'" WHERE '.$valor1.'="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error());
```

Make sure you enter something in email field before hitting submit.

Comment: Cool! Glad you found the solution by yourself. var_dump() surely is the best way to start debugging, isn't it?